# AADB2C90205: Facing insufficient permission while getting the refresh token

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have programmatically created an Azure AD B2C app registration, generating a Client ID and Client Secret successfully. I can retrieve the authorization code using these credentials. However, when attempting to obtain the refresh token via the Azure tenant API, I am encountering an 'insufficient permission' issue.

API: `https://<b2cTenentName>.b2clogin.com/<b2cTenentName>.onmicrosoft.com/<policyName>/oauth2/v2.0/token`

Error:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADB2C90205: This application does not have sufficient permissions against this web resource to perform the operation.\r\nCorrelation ID: 17ef2c0a-9149-4694-8aa3-880ad73ea54c\r\nTimestamp: 2023-10-31 03:40:03Z\r\n"
}
```

I don't know how to give the access for read and write like user.read and user.writeAll.

Thank you for any guidance or insights on this matter.

Comment: Can you include the API permissions granted to the application and the call you are making to generate refresh token?

Comment: How to add the API permissions like user.Read in scope using Rest API

Comment: So you want to add offline_access scope to the Azure AD B2C Application using REST API to generate access token?

Comment: No, i can able to add offline_access scope using this PATCH API https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/appObjId/ and payload                 requiredResourceAccess: [ { resourceAppId: '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000',resourceAccess: [{ id: '7427e0e9-2fba-42fe-b0c0-848c9e6a8182', type: 'Scope', },{id: '37f7f235-527c-4136-accd-4a02d197296e',type: 'Scope', },{ id: 'https://<b2ctenentName>.onmicrosoft.com/node-api/<name>.Read', type: 'Scope', }, ],}, ],

but getting error

Comment: Are you trying to add https://<b2ctenentName>.onmicrosoft.com/node-api/<name>.Read scope using REST API?

Comment: Yes, i want to add the  https://<b2ctenentName>.onmicrosoft.com/node-api/<name>.Read scope

Answer (score 0):

I created an Azure AD B2C application and **exposed an API** like below:

[image]

**Get the ID of the API scope**, execute the below query:

*Service Principal ObjectID:*

[image]

**Query:**

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/ServicePrincipalObjID/oauth2PermissionScopes
```

[image]

Now, **I used the below query to assign `offline_access` and API scope** to the application API permission blade:

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/ObjID

{
"requiredResourceAccess": [
{
"resourceAppId": "ClientID",
"resourceAccess": [
{
"id": "b6ff1d24-2bbc-4a23-b514-XXXXX (IDfromabove)", 
"type": "Scope"
}
]
},
{
"resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
"resourceAccess": [
{
"id": "7427e0e9-2fba-42fe-b0c0-848c9e6a8182",
"type": "Scope"
}
]
}
]
}
```

[image]

The API permissions added in the application like below:

[image]

Comment: You'll also need to grant admin consent

Comment: Yes can be done by using Microsoft Graph API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/enterprise-apps/grant-admin-consent?pivots=ms-graph#grant-admin-consent-for-delegated-permissions-1 or using `https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenanTID/adminconsent?client_id=ClientID`

Comment: I'm creating the Azure AD B2C application programmatically using REST API. how to expose the API using REST API, instead of manually add