# In an Azure Active Directory App Registration, how can I expose an API (user_impersonation) programatically?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-cli

I am updating a Powershell script which creates and configures an number of App Registrations to build an IAM solution. The script has not been executed for approx 18 months while project priorities changed. It uses a mixture of calls to the Azure CLI and the Microsoft Graph interface to create several app registrations.

The steps involved in each app registration are broadly similar:

- Define a set of required resource accesses (a mix of scope and role accesses) for the app
- Create the App registration
- Create a Service Principal
- Iterate through the resources accesses and add them to the app as permissions

I've had to make a number of minor updates to get the script to run successfully (replacing references to `ObjectId`s with references to `Id`s, removing the use of a password in creating the app, and so on.)

The script now runs without error, but my problem is that the behaviour is not the same as before.

Previously, for each App Registration, an API was exposed with scope `user_impersonation`:

[image: Exposed API when script was originally run]

This was reflected in the manifest as a set of `oauth2Permissions`:

[image: OAuth2Permissions as seen in Manifest when script was run originally]

However, when I run the revised script no API is exposed, and no `oauth2Permissions` are set:

[image: OAuth2Permissions as currently seen in Manifest]

My question is: how can I set the oauth2Permissions and expose the API with the user_impersonation scope **programmatically **, rather than through the Admin Console.

(I have searched the Microsoft documentation for details on setting OAuth2Permissions, but have only found details of manipulating [OAuth2PermissionGrant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/oauth2permissiongrant?view=graph-rest-1.0)s, which are not the same thing.)

Answer (score 0):

**To set the Application ID URI**, make use of below PowerShell script:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Application.ReadWrite.All"

$params = @{
    identifierUris = @(
        "https://b2caadtenant.onmicrosoft.com/AppID"
    )
}
Update-MgApplication -ApplicationId AppObjID -BodyParameter $params
```

[image]

In Portal, Application ID URI is updated:

[image]

**To create scopes,** make use of below script:

```
$api = @{
    oauth2PermissionScopes = @(
        @{
        AdminConsentDescription = "user_impersonation"
        AdminConsentDisplayName = "user_impersonation"
        Type = "Admin"
        Value = "user_impersonation"
        Id = $([guid]::NewGuid())
    }
    )
}
Update-MgApplication -ApplicationId AppObjID -Api $api
```

[image]

Scope created successfully:

[image]

Now, you can **fetch the scopes** created by using below Microsoft Query:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/SPObjID/oauth2PermissionScopes
```

[image]

***Output:***

```json
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#servicePrincipals('xxx')/oauth2PermissionScopes",
"value": [
{
"adminConsentDescription": "user_impersonation",
"adminConsentDisplayName": "user_impersonation",
"id": "786912f0-1cd0-496b-b619-XXX",
"isEnabled": true,
"type": "Admin",
"userConsentDescription": null,
"userConsentDisplayName": null,
"value": "user_impersonation"
}
]
}
```

To **assign above scope as permission in API permission blade**, make use of below script:

```
$params = @{
    requiredResourceAccess = @(
        @{
            resourceAppId = "ClientID"
            resourceAccess = @(
                @{
                    id = "IDfromthe ABove"
                    type = "Scope"
                }
            )
        }
    )
}
Update-MgApplication -ApplicationId 6646189d-84ef-4f40-9d26-895654ad01b4 -BodyParameter $params
```

[image]

[image]

**Reference:**

[azure - AADB2C90205: Facing insufficient permission while getting the refresh token - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77393119/aadb2c90205-facing-insufficient-permission-while-getting-the-refresh-token) by me